ContentBytes field in Microsoft Graph fileAttachment object is null while size field is non-zero
Problem is described in the question title.
Test Environment: Newly provisioned 365 tenant with one user on a business standard license.
Goal: Retrieve an email attachment's content from the graph API.
Method:

Retrieve a list of attachments from graph: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/mailFolders/inbox/messages/{messageId}/attachments?$select=id,name,contentType,size,isInline
Retrieve the contentBytes field of an attachment by its id: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/messages/{messageId}/attachments/{attachmentId}/$value

Expected Behavior:
When an attachment's size field is non-zero, we expect the request in step #2 to return a non-zero number of bytes.
Actual Behavior:
For specific attachments, the response contains zero bytes.
Looking up the attachment by its id using Graph Explorer shows a non-zero size field but a null contentBytes field

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Are there any special characters in attached file? What's the encoding of the file? Is it possible to share a file with us?

@user2250152 I cannot answer for this specific attachment, as this email was generated by microsoft and we do not have the file. However, we have observed this issue with application/pdf types that do not contain special characters. Sadly, we cannot share these pdf files. I have a support ticket open with Microsoft for this issue since 7/3 and will provide updates as they become available.
